# Align text within a Reaction created grid

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-data-grid

I'm using a grid that uses React Data Grid (https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid) and I am having troubles since when a cell is selected its border covers the next cell's text. I have gone through the "exploratory programming" route but I can't understand where to add the code to align the text.

```
` .react-grid-Container {
  clear: both;
}
.react-grid-Main {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: inherit;
  outline: 1px solid #e7eaec;
  clear : both;
}
.react-grid-Grid {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.react-grid-Canvas {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.react-grid-Cell {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid #111;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.react-grid-Cell:not(.editing) .react-grid-Cell__value {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.react-grid-Canvas.opaque .react-grid-Cell:not(.editing) {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.react-grid-Row:hover .react-grid-Cell,
.react-grid-Row.row-context-menu .react-grid-Cell {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
/*....
Some code that handles editing
......*/
.react-grid-Header {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #dddddd;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}
.react-grid-HeaderCell {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.react-grid-HeaderCell__value {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.react-grid-Cell:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
.react-grid-Cell.selected {
  border: 2px solid #66afe9;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 10;
}`
```

Have I missed something obvious or is there something with the Reaction framework that interfere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create solution, an ugly solution but still. I simply added a style and text-align tag that is pointing to the whole body and that made sure that React didn't overwrite the changes.